# Does Conv2d applied in vgg16 automatically apply an activation function?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, distance

My goal is to investigate the differences in the activations across the different layers of a neural network.
I've tried to simplify my example, and I hope nothing got lost in translation! Otherwise i can add some more code, and clarify!
I'm working with vgg-16 in pytorch (https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/vgg.py)

I've attached the following hook

```
# a dict to store the activations
activation = {}
def getActivation(name):
    # the hook signature
    def hook(model, input, output):
        activation[name] = output.detach()
    return hook
```

to each of the layers in model.features.

I've then presented the algorithm with 2 pictures, and i want to extract the euclidian distance between these.
I've done so by iterating through the layers, flattening the matrix of activations with the .flatten function, and calculating the distance with torch.cdist.

When i plot the distance of the activations, the layers of vgg-16, where the calls to Conv2d are always followed by a ReLU function, the output of the Conv2d layer and the output from the ReLU layer are identical! (examples are layer 19(Conv2d layer) and 20(ReLU layer), and again in layer 21(Conv2d layer) and layer 22(ReLU layer).

Plot of distance "between" activations can be seen at https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpxuy.png

This lead me to think that maybe Conv2d automatically applied the ReLU, like it can in the Keras framework's tf.keras.layers.Conv2D.
When reading the documentation, and the source code, it does not seem like it.
Does anyone have an explanation for why activation from my Conv2d layers and my subsequent ReLU layers are all exactly the same?

Comment: Would help to show a [mcve], including the code that calculates the Euclidean distance with an example where you observe this behaviour.

Comment: I've made a version which shows my issues:
https://github.com/Ondonden/deepVisualization
Let me know if it's still unclear!